# How to change commands in a player?

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3

I have an instance of `ExoPlayer`

```
player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
```

I can check available commands as follows:

```
val commands = player.availableCommands
val size = commands.size()
for (i in 0 until size)
   Log.d(TAG, "${commands[i]}")
```

The output:

```
1
2
3
4
10
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
```

**How do i change the available commands ? For example how can i delete the first one or add some new comand ?**